# Flutter/ How to get Google Fonts Family List

Tags: flutter, google-font-api, google-fonts

Hello I am developing app with Flutter.

To manage the fonts in my App, I am using

https://pub.dev/packages/google_fonts

Package.

So I plan to user can choice font that they want.

Is there any way I can get the entire list of google font family ?

```
List<String> _tempFontList = [
  GoogleFonts.droidSerif().fontFamily,
  GoogleFonts.ebGaramond().fontFamily,
  GoogleFonts.fasterOne().fontFamily,
  GoogleFonts.abel().fontFamily,
];
```

For now I made just temp List for the fonts,

But as I see there is no list getList functions in that package.

Thanks for reading.

I will Waite for your help.

Comment: Its in the documentation, [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_fonts/latest/google_fonts/GoogleFonts-class.html)

Comment: I'm having the same issue can the answer be posted so people having the same issue can solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

In order to get the list of fonts.

`GoogleFonts.asMap();`

that will return the Map object.

if you just want the names.

`GoogleFonts.asMap().keys.toList();`

Comment: This is an almost perfect and definitely pretty clever solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's no getter to get the list of fonts supported by this package, but you can see the list from(package) [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/material-foundation/flutter-packages/main/packages/google_fonts/lib/google_fonts.dart)

Comment: There is , asMap Can be used. I Found it Thanks.

Comment: Oh there it is. Sorry & Thanks :)

Comment: The link is now broken.